# Javafx - Clipboard content deleted when program ends

Tags: java, javafx, clipboard

I set Clipboard content via `clipboard.setContent(content)` which works fine.
But when the program ends via `System.exit(0)` the clipboard content is deleted.
When I end the program by clicking the cross in the titlebar the clippboard is still set.
So is there a way to end my programm which doesn't delete the clipboard like `System.exit(0)` does?

Thank you:)

Comment: which OS are you using? Which Java version?

Comment: Windows 8.1 and Java Version 8 Update 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying the following code:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("sample");
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

The clipboard is properly filled even after program end and its `System.exit(0)` call.

You mentioned to invoke a `clipboard.setContent(content)`, but the [Clipboard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html#method.summary) class does not provide such a method.

I would double check your code and compare against the one above. Also check to properly invoke the right method.

---

**UPDATE**
The previous answer was based on the assumption of Awt/Swing application. However, after your latest edits to the question, it seems to be a JavaFX application.

The following suggestion worked out: replace the call to `System.exit(0)` by `Platform.exit()`.

Comment: There is a ClipboardContent Class where .setContent() exists. This solution does not work for me because there seems to be a problem using awt with Javafx.

Comment: But  you just changed the title from Java to JavaFX, which of course changes now the context (and the potential answer)

Comment: Yes. Im sorry. I forgot to change that earlier

Comment: Did you try to invoke Platform.exit() instead of System.exit(0)?

Comment: Ok, I'll update the answer accordingly then, otherwise AWT and JavaFX get mixed incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you used the local Clipboard and not the system Clipboard.
Read following Example: [System Clipboard](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82)

Btw: I also use Windows 8.1 and Java Version 8 Update 45

Comment: I made it this way: `final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString("String here");
        clipboard.setContent(content);`

Comment: Well that should be the correct way. I see you are using th Clipboard for JavaFX ?

Comment: Yes. Is there a command which does the same as the cross at the titlebar? Or is there any alternative to System.exit(0)?

Comment: I tried the same, and for me it works perfect.  May be there is another application which is running and override your clipboard. Have you running an old instance of your application ?